# ajax not adding data to database

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to send the array `selectedItems` to my database using ajax but for some reason this isn't working for me.

Every time I click on the button that calls to `deposit()` I first get alert:

> "Thank you, We will send you a trade request as soon as possible!"

but then i get the alert:

> "something went wrong, please try again."

because `$_POST["setDeposit"]` isn't set.

**Javascript:**

```
function deposit() {
    var selectedItems = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"];
    if (selectedItems.length !== 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://csgodonut.com/home/depositdone',
            data:{setDeposit:selectedItems},
            success:function() {
                alert("Thank you, We will send you a trade request as soon as possible!");
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Please select atleast one item.");
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function depositdone() {
    if(isset($_POST['setDeposit'])) {
        $array = $_POST['setDeposit'];
        $depositItems = implode("<>", $array);
        $steamid = $steamprofile["steamid"];

        $tradeurl = $this->home_model->get_trade_url($steamid);

        if ($tradeurl !== NULL) {
            $this->home_model->add_deposit($tradeurl, $steamid, $depositItems);
            header("Location:/home");
        } else {
            echo '<script>alert("You don\'t have a Tradelink set, please click on your name to set it!");</script>';
            header("Location:/home");
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>
        if (confirm('something went wrong, please try again.')) {
            window.location.replace('http://csgodonut.com/home');
        } else {
            window.location.replace('http://csgodonut.com/home');
        }
        </script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken so far?

Comment: Don't return a script tag -- that's just weird. Store what you need in some sort of JSON object e.g. `{ message: "You don't...", redirect: "http://csgodonut.com/home" }` and in your success handler, do the appropriate action based on the keys given.

Comment: How are you calling `deposit()`? It sounds like you're not preventing the normal form submission, so that's happening after the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything on failure.

the ajax function as an error function that is called.

Please look at the adjusted sample.  There's no way to troubleshoot an error if you mask it.

I also recommend some logging on the server side that will help diagnose problems.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://csgodonut.com/home/depositdone',
            data:{setDeposit:selectedItems},
            success:function() {
                alert("Thank you, We will send you a trade request as soon as possible!");
            },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, theError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(theError);
      }
        });
```